# Check input form need two click to be validated

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need to click two times on my button to validate my form,

I have a event listener like this :

```
btnCartSend.addEventListener('click', function(){
checkInput();
window.location="confirm.html "
})
```

Then it call

```
   function checkInput(){
 if (fristName.length == 0){
    alert("test 1");
 }else if(lastName.length == 0){
    alert("test 2");
 }else if(address.length == 0){
    alert("test 3");
 }else if(zip.length != 5){
    alert("test 4");
 }else if(city.length == 0){    
    alert("test 5");
 }else if(email.length == 0){
    alert("test 6");
 }else {    
    console.log('send to api'); 
    sendToApi();
 }
}
```

I put the whole project on my github and here you have the cart file with both functions and others: https://github.com/lliolla/P5-onorico/blob/master/frontend/js/cart.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned your project and find some omissions that you are using shoppingCart.length everywhere while shoppingCart is having null initially, so wherever you are using the length or any other property, please first check if that variable is null or not.

After fixing all this, I have run the code and it is validating the form with a single click.

Check your code or replace the cart.js with the below code I have corrected at some places.

```
//déclaration des variables
let shoppingCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));  // recuperer le panier convertit en javascript
console.log('shoppingCart',shoppingCart)
let orderInfos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderInfos'));  // recuperer le retour API convertit en javascript
console.log('orderInfos',orderInfos)

let form =document.getElementById("form") // formulaire
let btnCartSend =document.getElementById("btnCartSend") // bouton envoi

let tableCartRows = document.getElementById("tableCartRows")// corps du tableau
let tableFoot = document.getElementById("tableFoot")//pied du tableau
let table=document.getElementById("table") // tableau entier
let tableTitle=document.getElementById("tableTitle") // h2

let orderModal = document.getElementById('orderModal')// modal de confirmation de commande

//variables info clients a vérifier
let fristName = document.getElementById("inputFristName").value;
let lastName= document.getElementById("inputLastName").value;
let address = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
let zip = document.getElementById("inputZip").value;
let city = document.getElementById("inputCity").value;
let email = document.getElementById("InputMail").value;



function showCart(){
//au chargement de la page génerer dynamiquement le panier si shoppingcart est plein sinon on affiche panier vide avec bouton de retour a teddiesHome.html
        if (shoppingCart && shoppingCart.length <= 0) {
            // on masque le cart le formulaire et son bouton et on affiche un retour à la page des produits
            tableTitle.style.display = "none";
            tableCart.style.display = "none";
            form.style.display = "none";
            btnCartSend.style.display = "none";

            let h2 = document.createElement("h2");
            table.appendChild(h2);
            h2.textContent ="Votre panier est vide ";
            let p = document.createElement("p");
            table.appendChild(p);
            p.textContent ="Faites un petit tour dans nos boutiques et laissez-vous tenter";

            var a = document.createElement("a");
            p.appendChild(a);
            a.setAttribute('class','btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block');
            a.setAttribute('href','teddiesHome.html');
            a.setAttribute('role','button');
            a.textContent = "Continuer mes achats";

            }else{
                
            totalCartPrice ();// total price du panier
            //verifier si il y a des doublons
            if(shoppingCart) {
                createTableCart();  //sinon afficher le panie
            }
        }
}
showCart()

 function delateItemCart(index){
    //supprimer un teddy en fonction de son index dans teddyArray
    console.log ("suprimer le teddy dans shopping cart",index, shoppingCart[index])
    shoppingCart.splice(index,1)
    console.log ("suprimer le teddy dans shopping cart", shoppingCart)
    //vide le localstorage
    localStorage.clear();
    //mettre à jour le local storage avec nouveau panier
     localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart',JSON.stringify(shoppingCart) ) ;
    totalCartPrice ();
     // recharger la page
     document.location.reload();
//}

 }

// on fait une boucle pour acceder à tous les boutons supprimer
 let bntDelated = document.querySelectorAll('.bntDelated') //boutons supprimer
 for (i=0 ;i<bntDelated.length ; i++ ){
    console.log("bntDelated", bntDelated[i])

    bntDelated[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ // au clic sur sup on suprimer le teddy coorepondant dans le shopping cart
            let index = Array.from(bntDelated).indexOf(event.target) ;

            console.log("click pour suprimer envoi l'index, ",index)
            delateItemCart(index);
            })
 }




// au clic sur le btn envoyer la commande
btnCartSend.addEventListener('click', function(){
    checkInput();// on verifie le format des input
    sendToApi(); // on envoi les donnees a l'api et on recuperer le num de commande
    //si tout est ok on affiche le modal avec un num de commande et le prix total
window.location="confirm.html "
})



function totalCartPrice (){
    if(shoppingCart) {
        let totalCart = 0;
         for ( let i=0; i<shoppingCart.length ; i++ ){
            let cartQte =  shoppingCart[i].qte;
            let cartprice =  shoppingCart[i].price;
            totalCart += cartQte * cartprice
         localStorage.setItem('totalCart',JSON.stringify(totalCart) );
     }
    }
}

function createTableCart(){// on affiche dynamiquement le panier sous forme de tableau

// on boucle le shopping cart pour afficher une ligne par teddy
     for ( let i=0; i<shoppingCart.length ; i++ ){

        let tr1 = document.createElement("tr");
        tableCartRows.appendChild(tr1);

        let th7 = document.createElement("th");
        tr1.appendChild(th7);
        th7.setAttribute('scoop','row');
        th7.textContent="counter ligne";

        let td = document.createElement("td");
        tr1.appendChild(td);
        let teddyname =shoppingCart[i].name ;
        td.textContent= teddyname;
        td.setAttribute("id","Name")

        let td1 = document.createElement("td");
        tr1.appendChild(td1);
        let teddyColor = shoppingCart[i].colors;
        td1.textContent=teddyColor;
        td.setAttribute("id","Color")

        let price = shoppingCart[i].price  + "€";
        let td2 = document.createElement("td");
        tr1.appendChild(td2);
        td2.textContent=price;

        let td3 = document.createElement("td");
        tr1.appendChild(td3);
        td3.setAttribute("class","counter");

        let div = document.createElement("div");
        td3.appendChild(div);
        div.setAttribute("class","number");
        div.setAttribute("id","number");

        div.textContent=shoppingCart[i].qte;

        // let div1 = document.createElement("div")
        // td3.appendChild(div1)
        // div1.setAttribute("class","counter-clic")

        // let i1 = document.createElement("i")
        // div1.appendChild(i1)
        // i1.setAttribute("class","fas fa-plus plus")

        // let i2 = document.createElement("i")
        // div1.appendChild(i2)
        // i2.setAttribute("class","fas fa-minus minus")

        // let td4 = document.createElement("td")
        // tr1.appendChild(td4)
        // td4.textContent= subTotal

        let td5 = document.createElement("td");
        tr1.appendChild(td5);
        td5.setAttribute("class","text-center");

        let i3 = document.createElement("i");
        td5.appendChild(i3);
        i3.setAttribute("class","fas fa-times-circle bntDelated");



    }
    let tr2 = document.createElement("tr");
    tableFoot.appendChild(tr2);

    let td6 = document.createElement("td");
    tr2.appendChild(td6);
    td6.setAttribute("colspan","2");

    let td7 = document.createElement("td");
    tr2.appendChild(td7);
    td7.textContent = "Total"

    let totalCart = localStorage.getItem('totalCart')
    let td8 = document.createElement("td");
    tr2.appendChild(td8);
    td8.setAttribute("colspan","3");
    td8.setAttribute('class','text-right');
    td8.textContent = totalCart + "€";

}


function checkInput(){
    if (fristName.length == 0){
         alert("test 1");
    }else if(lastName.length == 0){
         alert("test 2");
    }else if(address.length == 0){
         alert("test 3");
    }else if(zip.length != 5){
         alert("test 4");
    }else if(city.length == 0){
         alert("test 5");
    }else if(email.length == 0){
         alert("test 6");
    }else {
         console.log('send to api');
         sendToApi();
    }
 }


function sendToApi(){
// crerer un objet qui va recuperer la value de chaque input du formulaire
    //creation de la class client
    class customer{
        constructor(fristName,lastName,address,city,email){
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.fristName = fristName;
            this.address = address;
            this.city = city;
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
    // objet contenant les infos du formulaire
    let newCustumer = new customer (lastName,fristName, address,city,email)

// creer un tableau pour envoyer uniquement les ID des teddy
    //recupérer le shoppingCart
    let apiCart =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart")) ;
    console.log("apiCart",apiCart)
    let apiCartArray = []; // tableau des id des teddy

    //parcourir le tableau et recuperer les id des teddy
    if(apiCart) {
        for (let i=0; i<apiCart.length; i++){

            apiCartArray.push(apiCart[i].id)
            console.log("send api id",apiCartArray)
        }
    }

// POST API
     fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          contact: {
            firstName: newCustumer.fristName,
            lastName: newCustumer.lastName,
            address: newCustumer.address,
            city: newCustumer.city,
            email: newCustumer.email,
          },
          products: apiCartArray,
        }),
       })
       .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
       })
       .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("orderInfos", JSON.stringify(data));
       })
       .catch((error) => console.log("erreur de type : ", error));
}
```